# How does Rotation and pivoting work in javafx?

Tags: javafx

I have seen the questions asked in this website about rotation in javafx but I don't seem to grasp it. Here is some code:

```
    import javafx.application.Application; 
    import javafx.scene.Group; 
    import javafx.scene.Scene; 
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color; 
    import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle; 
    import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate; 
    import javafx.scene.transform.Scale; 
    import javafx.scene.transform.Translate; 
    import javafx.stage.Stage; 

    public class TransformationsExample extends Application { 
        @Override 
        public void start(Stage stage) { 
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 75);      
            rectangle.setFill(Color.BURLYWOOD);      
            rectangle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);     
            Rotate rotate = new Rotate();    
            rotate.setAngle(90);         
            rotate.setPivotX(150); 
            rotate.setPivotY(225); 
            rectangle.getTransforms().addAll(rotate);              
            Group root = new Group(rectangle);  
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1400, 780);      
            stage.setTitle("Transformations"); 
            stage.setScene(scene); 
            stage.show(); 
        }      
        public static void main(String args[]){ 
            launch(args); 
        } 
    }
```

Why is it that when I change the angle, the rectangle starts appearing in random places? For example, when I set angle to 180, the rectangle appears in the middle. My understanding is that the rectangle moves in specified angle around X: 150 and Y:225. However, when I set the angle to 180, I am completely wrong. Can you guys help me out?

Edit: While reading and seeing the code answered to this question, I think I found a new question. How do you set a pivoting distance from pivotX and pivotY?

Edit2: This is for user @Slaw. I hope to know how you can find/set X?
[image: X = ?]

Comment: The code appears to do what you think it should—assuming I understand your expectations. Try executing a slightly modified version of your code, https://gist.github.com/tkslaw/6a5f75e43148e3be54e60a3532a30299, that animates the rectangle and shows the pivot point. Does it make more sense? Or do you still expect something different? Note your pivot point is _outside_ the rectangle.

Comment: @Slaw, that was highly informative in showing me the pivoting points, thank you! If pivotX is 150 & pivotY is 225, the rectangle will revolve around those points. But, one question is, where does the distance between the rectangle and the red dot come from? Nowhere during the code has a distance been set. I want the rectangle to be as close as possible to the red dot. How do I do that?

Comment: Not the pivoting point, the pivoting distance? Like, how far the rectangle is away from the red dot? How do I find that distance? @Slaw

Comment: @Slaw, say I want to put the rectangle at the location (610, 275) with the rectangle rotated 180 degrees. How do i do that?

Comment: If you want to rotate the rectangle about its center then you have to bind the pivot point to the center of the rectangle: `(x + width / 2, y + height / 2)`.

Comment: These transformations appear to take place in the local coordinate space of the object being transformed. Note there's a difference in the way `boundsInLocal` are calculated between "regular" `Node`s and `Shape`s.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace the line

```
Group root = new Group(rectangle);
```

with the following two lines

```
Circle pivot = new Circle(150, 225, 5, Color.BLACK);
Group root = new Group(rectangle, pivot);
```

and then increment your angle in small steps 0, 10, 45, 90 degrees, the behaviour becomes clearer I think and is exactly what I would expect.

Comment: I have asked this question before but where does the distance between the circle and the rectangle come from? Most importantly, how do I set the distance to a certain value?

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer my question.